# Get array from dynamic variable

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is really simple, I just can't work out how to do it.

I want to dynamically make an array from one variable equal to another:

```
 var pageID = document.getElementsByClassName('page_example')[0].id;
```

Let's say this returned an id of page_1

```
 var page_1 = ['value1','value2','value3'];
 var page_2 = ['value4','value5','value6'];
 var page_3 = ['value7','value8','value9'];

var page_array = (then have the associated pageID's array here)
```

So in this example,

```
page_array would equal ['value1','value2','value3']
```

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand, but you could do this: `var page_array = eval("page_1")`. You should provide more code

Comment: Looking at your markup will really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the array in separate variables, store them in an object with the ids as the key:

```
var pages = {
    page_1: ['value1','value2','value3'],
    page_2: ['value4','value5','value6'],
    page_3: ['value7','value8','value9']
}
```

You can access the arrays as though the object was an assosiative array:

```
var pageID = "page_1";
var pageArray = pages[pageID];
```

Comment: Thank you, all I needed to do was `var page_array = eval(pageID)`. Your method is much cleaner though!

Comment: @wadclapp Be extremly careful with eval. The user might change the pageID to some malicious code in the browser developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you would like to achieve, you can one of two or three methods.

What I consider the easiest method is an if/else statement:

```
if (condition) {
 page_array = page_1.slice(0);
} else if (other condition) {
 page_array = page_2.slice(0);
} else if...
```

Another method you can use, again depending on what your ultimate goal is, would be a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfDesiredLoops; i++) {
  page_array = page_1.slice(0, i);
}
```

Or you could use a combination of both:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfDesiredLoops; i++) {
  if (condition) {
    page_array = page_1.slice(0); 
  } else if (other condition) {
    page_array = page_2.slice(1);
  } else if...
}
```

With more information on why you need this variable to change, I can give you a better answer.

edit: keep in mind the arguments of `.slice()` can be whatever you want.

Comment: For further information on .slice() -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice